# A game library for Node with architecturally separated runner and renderer

Tags: node.js, socket.io, 2d-games

I am building a simple game with Node. I use socket.io for communication between devices.

I want the node server to handle all the game logic; collision detection, scores ect.

The Node (socket.io) server should then send some display infomation to clients; player position, score, map size ect.

The client should also be able to send navigation commands to the server, like up and down. It might also need collision detection to avoid that you try to step out of the map ect, there is no need for us to send the navigation data then.

My question is, are there any libarys that handle this kind of logic? I know there are some game libs out there for JS, but as far I can see they are for handling the logic and rendering, and are not made to be used on a Node server.

[image: How I think it could work]

I have used [Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/) for both rendering and logic before. I am thinking that I'll draw the game with [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: Off topic, but I like your state diagram. Which tool did you use to draw it?

Comment: I used this: http://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [BonsaiJS](http://bonsaijs.org/).
It's a nice Ghapic Libary with an architecturally separated runner and renderer.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe try the SDK from [GameClosure](http://www.gameclosure.com/)?  My understanding is that it has a lot of that sort of stuff available, though I've not used it myself.

That said, the idea of just doing everything on the server is a little bit odd.  The performance and responsiveness of your game is going to become very dependent on the player's connection to the server.  There are other schemes that have been implemented for many years in multiplayer game servers, which is a kind of client-side calculation with the server ensuring that the clients are doing that calculation correctly.  Is there a reason it all needs to be done server-side?

Comment: The game logic should end up pretty simple, it's a multiplayer game so it just makes sense for me to do it on the server, ensuring correct data. I could make the server validate things, but it seems far more easy to make the server do the logic and ensure sync this way, the other way around we could end up with one player winning locally, while the other player also won. But I am open for suggestions, if you have anything specific that would do the job please share!

Comment: It would also allow me to have a 3 device setup for example: 1 iPad for the game board, and two phones as controllers, with no problems.

Comment: Ah, OK, I think I understand.  I am not aware of any libraries that are going to take care of that specific part for you, I'm afraid.